# Kafka 0.10 SASL/PLAIN producer timeout

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, sasl

I've got a 3 broker kerberised Kafka 0.10 install running in Cloudera and I'm trying to authenticate with SASL/PLAIN

I'm passing kafka_server_jaas.conf into the JVM on each of the brokers.

`KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username=admin
  password=password1
  user_admin=password1
  user_remote=password1;
};`

My `server.properties` (or `kafka.properties` as Cloudera renames it) is set as below;

`listeners=SASL_SSL://10.10.3.47:9093 # ip set for each broker
advertised.listeners=SASL_SSL://10.10.3.47:9093 # ip set for each broker
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=GSSAPI,PLAIN
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=GSSAPI`

When Kafka starts up, the inter-broker communication is all fine, but when I try to connect using the console producer I get a Timeout failed to update metadata

`bin/kafka-consolproducer --broker-list 10.10.3.161:9093 --topic test1 --producer.config client.properties.plain`

client.properties.plain is set to

`security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN`

finally, the client side jaas.conf

`KafkaClient {
        org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
        username="remote"
        password="password1";
};`

As far as I can tell I've followed all instructions correctly, can anyone see anything wrong?

**Update**
I've turned the logging on the console consumer up a bit, I'm getting the following error;

`[2017-03-02 13:17:50,817] TRACE SSLHandshake NEED_UNWRAP channelId -1, handshakeResult Status = OK HandshakeStatus = FINISHED
bytesConsumed = 101 bytesProduced = 0, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 101 (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2017-03-02 13:17:50,817] TRACE SSLHandshake FINISHED channelId -1, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 101  (org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer)
[2017-03-02 13:17:50,817] DEBUG Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator)
[2017-03-02 13:17:50,818] DEBUG Set SASL client state to INITIAL (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator)
[2017-03-02 13:17:50,819] DEBUG Set SASL client state to INTERMEDIATE (org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator)
[2017-03-02 13:17:50,820] DEBUG Connection with <IPADDESS_REMOVED> disconnected (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer.read(SslTransportLayer.java:488)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:81)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveResponseOrToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:239)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:182)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:64)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:318)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:283)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.clientPoll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:360)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:134)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:183)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:974)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:938)
        at kafka.consumer.NewShinyConsumer.<init>(BaseConsumer.scala:61)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:64)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:51)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
[2017-03-02 13:17:50,821] DEBUG Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)`

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with the included performance test producer tool.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Can you try with 0.10.2 ? I was facing similar problem when configuring sasl plaintext with 0.10.0, I upgraded to 0.10.2 (broker and client libraries) and it worked.

Comment: Limited a little in which version we can use - deviation from Cloudera's supported combinations can cause issues. They're looking into it... reassuringly they're having problems too. I'll report back if a solution is ever found

Comment: In the end, I went for SSL only to allow the remote access, not ideal but got us moving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue with SASL_PLAINTEXT auth. I was able to connect to the broker (via kafka-python), but any messages I sent from the producer would simply time out.

I ended up advertising both SASL_PLAINTEXT and PLAINTEXT listeners, but only publicly exposed the SASL_PLAINTEXT listener via AWS security groups.

My server_jaas.conf was basically the same.

My server.properties used these settings:

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=PLAIN
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://example.com:9095,PLAINTEXT://example.com:9092
listeners = SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9095,PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
```

I was debugging this with the kafka-python client and my command looked like this (python)

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='example.com:9095', security_protocol="SASL_PLAINTEXT", sasl_mechanism='PLAIN', sasl_plain_username='username', sasl_plain_password='password')
```

With this setup I was able to have username/password authentication and also produce and consume messages to the broker without timeouts.

Hope this helps in some way :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was no need for adding a plaintext listener or for advertising the listener. Instead, the issue was in my *kafka_server_jaas.conf*. Setting the `username` property to the name used by the client to log in solved the issue for me.